# Is the XOR of n distinct numbers always a number outside the set of n numbers?

Tags: algorithm, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, xor

Assume you are given n distinct numbers, which may or may not have a gap in between them. If you were to XOR all the numbers, the result that you get, would it be be guaranteed to not be any of those n numbers?

Answer (score 3):

`0b00 XOR 0b01 XOR 0b10 XOR 0b11 == 0b00`

Answer (score 2):

No.

Assuming you meant that the first number in the array will be XOR'd with the 2nd, and the result of that would be XOR'd with the 3rd, etc, then consider the below counterpoint:

[1,2,6,4]

Using a binary XOR, see below bit representations:

100 XOR 010 = 110

110 XOR 011 = 101

101 XOR 001 = 100

The XOR of all the numbers in the array is equal to the first number in the array.

Comment: order and implementation don't matter due to commutativity and associativity of the xor-operation. But nice example.

Answer (score 1):

The number 0 has a pretty interesting trait in this context:

```
a xor 0 = a, a != 0
```

This is already half of the answer to the question:
XOR-ing the content of any set `{a, 0}, a != 0` would yield `a` as result. Thus the answer is no.

This can be expanded even further:
For any set of numbers `N`, where a subset `M` with the properties `M = N \ {a}` and `xor(M) = 0` exists, `xor(N) = a` holds. `M` has the property that the number of 1bits on any bit-position would be even:

```
N = {100, 010, 001, 011}
a = 100
M = {010, 001, 011}

    M:  0 1 0
        0 0 1
        0 1 1
count:  0 2 2

xor(N) = 100
```